# group by ID, then check the last row in two specific columns if it's equal to value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have dataFrame which is this:

| ID | Age | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | m |
| 1 | 13 | n |
| 1 | 14 | r |
| 1 | 15 | r |
| 2 | 11 | l |
| 2 | 22 | f |
| 2 | 33 | f |
| 2 | 55 | f |
| 3 | 150 | o |
| 3 | 160 | j |
| 3 | 170 | s |
| 3 | 180 | o |
| 4 | 10 | k |
| 4 | 20 | k |
| 4 | 30 | k |
| 4 | 40 | k |

I want first to group by ID, then check the last row on the (**name**) column on the grouped by dataFrame, if the last row is equal let's say **'r'** such as group (1) in our example , then go and check the last row in the age column of group(1)  as well,  if it's greater than specific number let's say that name ('r') which is the last row in the (name) column in group(1), it's last row (age) should be >= 15, if this condition of the age was satsified,  create another colum saying that the whole group is satsified or else unsatsified. the same thing again for the other last row of each group in the columns [names] and [ages].

so these are the other letters (name) and thier  (age) conditions:

in grouped by [ID] dataFrame, if the last row (name) is (r) the last row (age) should be >= 15, if the the last row (name) is (f) the last row (age) should be >= 55, if the last row (name) is (o) the last row (age) should be >= 182 ,if the last row (name) is (k) the last row (age) should be >= 50.

this is the last out put I am looking for:

| ID | Age | name | check_condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | m | satisfied |
| 1 | 13 | n | satisfied |
| 1 | 14 | r | satisfied |
| 1 | 15 | r | satisfied |
| 2 | 11 | l | satisfied |
| 2 | 22 | f | satisfied |
| 2 | 33 | f | satisfied |
| 2 | 55 | f | satisfied |
| 3 | 150 | o | unsatisfied |
| 3 | 160 | j | unsatisfied |
| 3 | 170 | s | unsatisfied |
| 3 | 180 | o | unsatisfied |
| 4 | 10 | k | unsatisfied |
| 4 | 20 | k | unsatisfied |
| 4 | 30 | k | unsatisfied |
| 4 | 40 | k | unsatisfied |

How can I do this by pandas python ?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Every row should be unsatisfied because grouped `ID` for 1,2 and 3 are not equal to `k` and for `ID` 4 the last row is `k` but `age<=60`

Comment: So basically I need a code that do the following:  groupby ID, Then for the grouped by data set, it will go to the name column let's say for group (1), it will check it's last row which is the (r), in our case , so since it's r, I need another condition which is going to the age column and check the last row in groupby (1), if the age >= 15 then I need satsified word in the new column

Comment: yes, that's what you already explained in your question, but then is your expected output wrong ?! ....or does the condition change (in the same df) for every ID

Comment: it is  actually change depends on the last row of the name in each groupby as well as last row on the age columns

Comment: so is the last row is (r) the age should be >= 15, if the last row is (f) the age should be >= 55, if the last row is (o) the age should be >= 182 , if the last row is (k) the age should be >= 50

Comment: Could you please edit your question so there are all informations and conditions to get from the original df to the expected output? That would help

Comment: yes sure I will do this now

Comment: is it clearer now ?

Comment: When you say "the last row of the age column", do you mean the last row of the age column *for each group*, or the last row of the age column for the entire DataFrame?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try group by then get the last row value of each group with `group.iloc[-1][col]`

```py
d = {'r': 15, 'f': 55, 'o': 182, 'k': 50}

df['check_condition'] = df['ID'].map(
    df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda group:
                           'satisfied' if group.iloc[-1]['Age'] >= d.get(group.iloc[-1]['name'])
                           else 'unsatisfied')
)
```

```
    ID  Age name check_condition
0    1   12    m       satisfied
1    1   13    n       satisfied
2    1   14    r       satisfied
3    1   15    r       satisfied
4    2   11    l       satisfied
5    2   22    f       satisfied
6    2   33    f       satisfied
7    2   55    f       satisfied
8    3  150    o     unsatisfied
9    3  160    j     unsatisfied
10   3  170    s     unsatisfied
11   3  180    o     unsatisfied
12   4   10    k     unsatisfied
13   4   20    k     unsatisfied
14   4   30    k     unsatisfied
15   4   40    k     unsatisfied
```